# save and search fingerprint in database using external scanner

Tags: android, database, operating-system, fingerprint

is it possible to create an android app that i can create users and search using fingerprint external scanner ?

1. is it possible to save fingerprint into database and find the fingerprint from it ?
2. if i use two different mark of fingerprint and i add user with the 1st one then i save the result into my db then if i use the 2nd one to search it can detect the presence of the fingerprint ? or the scanner that have created the user must also search him to find ?

Comment: The details will vary by scanner and what its manufacturer supports. Please contact the manufacturer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.